# pytorch training stucked when loading data from datasetloader

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I'm training a model with pytorch and it runs well at the beginning. But I got stucked when fetch data by dataloader at a random single loop. It seems that there is a deadlock but I don't know why

```
 for idx, (samples, targets) in enumerate(data_loader):
        samples = samples.cuda(non_blocking=True)
        targets = targets.cuda(non_blocking=True)

        # more code below..
```

When it got stucked, the gpu takes 0%

The original author of the code uses distributed trainning with --nproc_per_node = 8 GPUs, I changed it to 1.

the dataloader was initialized like below

```
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset_train, sampler=sampler_train,
        batch_size=config.DATA.BATCH_SIZE,
        num_workers=config.DATA.NUM_WORKERS,
        pin_memory=config.DATA.PIN_MEMORY,
        drop_last=True,
    )
```

where `dataset_train` is the instance of `torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder`, batch_size = 32, num_workers = 0 because somebody says that too many num_workers may cause deadlock but even I set it to 0, I still got the stuck.

When I enter the ctrl + c to interupt the process, it gives logs like:

```
^CWARNING:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api:Received 2 death signal, shutting down workers
WARNING:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:Sending process 9964 closing signal SIGINT
^CWARNING:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:Sending process 9964 closing signal SIGTERM
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 709, in run
    result = self._invoke_run(role)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 850, in _invoke_run
    time.sleep(monitor_interval)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/api.py", line 60, in _terminate_process_handler
    raise SignalException(f"Process {os.getpid()} got signal: {sigval}", sigval=sigval)
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api.SignalException: Process 9932 got signal: 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/yun/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/home/yun/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/home/yun/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "/home/yun/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/home/yun/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/home/yun/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 193, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 189, in main
    launch(args)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 174, in launch
    run(args)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 752, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 131, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 236, in launch_agent
    result = agent.run()
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/metrics/api.py", line 125, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 716, in run
    self._shutdown(e.sigval)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/local_elastic_agent.py", line 193, in _shutdown
    self._pcontext.close(death_sig)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/api.py", line 330, in close
    self._close(death_sig=death_sig, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/api.py", line 707, in _close
    handler.proc.wait(time_to_wait)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1083, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1800, in _wait
    time.sleep(delay)
  File "/home/yun/_Tools/anaconda3/envs/MSG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/api.py", line 60, in _terminate_process_handler
    raise SignalException(f"Process {os.getpid()} got signal: {sigval}", sigval=sigval)
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api.SignalException: Process 9932 got signal: 2
```

Anyone could give some suggestions? why this happend and how can I solve it?

After the debug, I found the code lead to the stack:

```py
for idx, (samples, targets) in enumerate(data_loader):
    outputs = model(samples)
       
    print(f"before synchronize ...",end="")
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    print(f" synchronized ...",end="")

    # more code below ...
```

In a random trainning loop, code runs at `torch.cuda.synchronize()` and stucked.